# Marking functions from a library as deprecated

Tags: c, gcc, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I'm working on a project in C which extends [an existing library](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) (via standard `include`s). As the library develops a number of functions become deprecated. However this is shown only in the documentation; the code does not mark this status in any way.

I'd like to have my project warn me whenever I attempt to use one of these deprecated functions, especially since the library is under active development so I might have used something before deprecation and not noticed when its status changed. Is there any way I can do this under gcc, short of modifying the library code itself? (For one thing, it changes often enough that keeping a local version with gcc attributes is impractical.)

Is this possible? It seems like Visual Studio could do this with its

```
#pragma deprecated(X,Y,...)
```

syntax, but I don't think gcc supports this, just

```
__attribute__ ((deprecated))
```

on a function declaration itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pulled from a working project

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define DEPRECATED(X) X __attribute__((deprecated))
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#define DEPRECATED(X) __declspec(deprecated) X
#else
#define DEPRECATED(X) X
#endif
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dabb5z75.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/044swk7y.aspx

Then

```
DEPRECATED(void foo(int a, int b, int c));
```

Comment: You don't have to. You just have to put this inside the declaration, not the definition

Comment: It's declared in the library -- I can't redeclare it in my file.

Comment: Why not? As long as you've gotten the prototypes down correctly it should compile fine and without warnings. To verify I've just tried  this in both MSVC (with `/W3`) and gcc (with `-Wall -Wextra`). You can declare functions as many times as you like so long that they retain the same storage class and arguments

Comment: I did not know that. Let me verify on my project and then I'll give you the checkmark. :)